# ReactJS select all similar tags for styling

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a table with two columns, and I want to style them such that the first column is styled as `text-align:left` and the second as `text-align:right`.

I am declaring styles like this:

```
const styles = {
    table: {
      width: '100%',
    } 
}
```

And the table looks like this:

```
<table style={styles.table}>   
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>   
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>   
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>   
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>   
  </tr> 
</table>
```

A verbose way to do it would be to create a style for each column and include them on every `<td>`. Any ways to select all td's (of one single column) at once?

Answer (score 1):

Just use pseudo-classes. For example:

```
td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
td:nth-chuld(2) {   //You can use :last-child instead of :nth-child(n) in your example
  text-align: right;
}
```

If it's not react-native just `import './styles.css'` in beginning of your component and use className for styling. Like this: `<table className='table'>...</table>`.

Comment: It doesn't work, I think css attributes with hyphens are not allowed in jsx

Comment: Is it react-native? Why you use style objects? If it's not react-native just `import './styles.css'` in beginning of your component and use className for styling. Like this: `<table className='table'>...</table>`. This will allow you to use regular css or sass/scss/less maybe :)